# SSRS Count Records expression with date less than group by date

Tags: date, reporting-services, count, iif

I want to count records that are not marked as completed with a Received date less than the Received date of the row (group by Received date "Details") This will be the Start of Day column showing how many records are in queue.

I have a tablix in VS 2017 SSDT.

Tablix is grouped by Received Date

```
COLUMNS
Received Date (group by Details) another column same field (Textbox5)
Start of Day        
New Tasks       
Completed
```

I'm having an issue with the code logic for Start of Day column field.

I want to count records that are not marked as completed with a Received date less than the Received date of the row (group by Received date "Details")

This code works for New Tasks column. 
`=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Received.Value < Fields!Received.Value AND 
    Fields!Completed.Value = "NO", 1,0),"Details")`

When I attempt the Start of Day expression I get errors. Textbox5 is the same dataset field used in group by field (Received). I added it to test different approach.

`=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Received.Value < ReportItems!Textbox5.Value AND 
Fields!Completed.Value = "NO", 1,0),"Details")`

> Error: rsAggregateReportItemlnBody aggregate functions can be used
>   only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Sample data and expected output for Start of Day Column: it should count records in the group by row if they were in queue prior to start of day (yesterday).

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question will be easier to understand if you can show some sample data as it comes from your dataset and expected output from the sample. Please edit your question and add some more details .

Comment: added sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use running value to calculate the total. To get the prior date total you subtract the group total value

Start Of Day

```
=  RunningValue( 1, SUM, "Tablix1")- SUM( 1)
```

New Task

```
= SUM(1) or COUNT(1)
```

Complete

```
=  RunningValue( Iif(Fields!CompYN.Value = "YES",1,0), SUM, "Tablix1")- SUM( Iif(Fields!CompYN.Value = "YES",1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks That worked! lots and lots of testing no solution. this has been verified with test data.. =RunningValue(Fields!COUNT.Value, COUNT, "Tablix3") - 
COUNT(IIF(Fields!Received.Value < Fields!Received.Value AND 
 Fields!Complete.Value = "NO", 1,0),"Details")

Comment: unfortunately it is not checking the completed part of the expression. does not take into consideration completed records should not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

New Tasks column: `=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Received.Value = Fields!Received.Value AND Fields!Completed.Value = "NO", 1,0),"Details")`

Start of day column: `=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Received.Value < Fields!Received.Value AND Fields!Completed.Value = "NO", 1,0),"Details")`

Comment: Didn't product expected results. trying to count if they are in queue before the grouped by received date and also not completed yet.. I tried this using the reportitems but got the aggregate error. 

=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Received.Value < ReportItems!Received.Value AND Fields!Completed.Value = "NO", 1,0),"Details")